# Android 3.0 fragmentation example?

Tags: android

I am working on android application. Now I am learning about android 3.0 Fragmentation.

I am already using the example of Android block. But it is not working. Please give me  another one example or please explain Android block fragmentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is in russian, try to understand the code from [here](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/113196/).

Comment: But the code and the comments inside the code are in English.

Comment: 03-29 19:23:28.222: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f050000, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.frag.AndroidFragapp

Comment: Here is the English version of the same article by official Android blog **http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html**

Answer (score 4):

here you can find another example ( in english =D )

**http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html**

Check the **TRACKBACKS**

Answer (score 2):

here you can find another example of fragment, try it.

http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/06/android-fragments-api/