# Passing Data From list-view to Edit-text Using Fragments?

Tags: android

I am developing an application which consists of two fragments.

1.Fragment(A) contains `ListView`.

2.Fragment(B) Contains `EditText`.

3.My problem is, How i pass the data from `ListView` to `EditText`,between the fragments, when  item is  selected in `ListView`,that data need to be displayed in EditText.How can i achieve this... I am new to android....

Answer (score 1):

See link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Write following method in your ListFragment:

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Append the clicked item's row ID with the content provider Uri
        Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArticleColumns.CONTENT_URI, id);
        // Send the event and Uri to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(noteUri);
    }
    ...
}
```

You need to implement  OnArticleSelectedListener in your activity, and in method,  get id from  article, and set on editText:

```
public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(Uri articleUri);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can pass the information up to the activity, and then the activity can pass it back down to the other fragment. If you already keep a handle to the adapter in your ListFragment, something like this might work:

```
protected MyActivity activity;

@override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Cursor c = adapter.getCursor();
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(nameOfColumn));

    activity.doSomethingWithName(name);
}
```

Then all you need is an appropriately defined method in yoru activity.

Comment: the below code i need to write in fragment(A),then how to declare in fragment(b),please canu explain me i am new to andorid.

Answer (score 0):

try http://android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/309-learn-how-to-implement-fragments-in-android
[Android 3.0 fragmentation example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459861/android-3-0-fragmentation-example)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example